# Unix command "sed" to replace PHP associative array values

Tags: php, arrays, sed

I am trying to use the Linux `sed` command to replace associative array values in a PHP config file. On macOS everything goes ok, but on linux I am getting an error.

Command

`sed -i .back "s/'param'.*=>.*/'param' => 'value',/" config.php`

> Error (linux): sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `.'

What proper solution would there be to replace PHP array values with the `sed` command?

Comment: show a fragment of your config file with associative array values to replace

Answer (score 2):

There must be no space between `-i` and `.back` on GNU sed:

```
sed -i.back 's/.../.../' file
```

If you don't care about the backup file you can omit the option value completely on GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's/.../.../' file
```